# Subset Selection Optimization

Tags: sql, excel, optimization, subset

I have a problem where I have to pick a set of ~500 providers from which I have to pick a subset which must obey certain criteria. Each member of this is evaluated according to 3 indicators (Indicator A, Indicator B, Indicator C). If a given member fulfills all criteria for all 3 indicators, it is described as (1,1,1). If it fulfills none, it is described as (0,0,0).

Combinations such as (1,0,1) or (0,1,0) are possible, but an indicator cannot be partially fulfilled (so (0.5, 0.9, 0,4) is impossible).

My goal is to find a subset of 50 members so that I can obtain a predefined overall achievement score on all 3 indicators. So, if I pick 50 members for my subset so that 48 fulfil indicator A, 23 fulfil indicator B and 33 fulfil indicator C, I will have a total achievement of 48/50 on indicator A, 23/50 on indicator B and 33/50 on indicator C.

Is there a way of implementing an algorithm that helps me find a subset so that I can meet predefined goals for each indicator?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Make sure you read these guidelines on how to post questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as we'll need some sample data to replicate your problem. Cheers.

Comment: You should use a bitwise indicator where hte fiirst is 1 or 0, the second, 2 or 0 and the third 4 or 0. A score of 7 would mean that all three indicators have been filled. A score of 5 would mean that the first and third indicator have been filled, etc.

Comment: Will sorting on the three columns put all the records to be selected together on the worksheet? What happens when you try that?

Comment: This is a "standard" ILP (Integer Linear Program) and a knapsack problem.  You can attempt to do this in Excel with the solver and BINARY selection variables, but if Excel's (feeble) solver chokes, you may need to transition to a more robust structure to set up and solve the ILP.